# hello, is there a way for consuming a Rest service in an app for windows 8.1 using WinJS?

Tags: rest, windows-8.1, winjs

hello I'm trying to consume a REST service in an app for windows 8.1, I'm so gratefull if you can give me more information related about this topic, thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms535874.aspx) object. But, since you are using WinsJS, the [WinJS.xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) function would be more convenient.

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {

        // Change RSS feed URL as you need to.
        var resDiv = document.getElementById("divResult"),
            rssURL = "http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/rss.aspx";

        // Call WinJS.xhr to retrieve an XML feed from the Web.
        WinJS.xhr({
            url: rssURL,
            responseType: "document"
        }).done(

            // When the result has completed, check the status.
            function completed(result) {
                if (result.status === 200) {

                    // Get the XML document from the results. 
                    var xmlDocument = result.responseXML,
                         title = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];

                    // Update the HTML in the app.
                    resDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
                    resDiv.innerText = "Downloaded RSS feed from the " + title.textContent + " blog.";
                }
            });
    };

    app.start();
})();
```

Comment: actually, since 8.1 the [httpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) is what Microsoft has been promoting instead of the "old" `WinJS.xhr`, since, as stated [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/09/06/updating-your-javascript-apps-to-use-the-new-windows-web-http-api/) it improves its (xhr) abilities